# If something with no specific time associated with it is called timeless, what would you call something with no specific place associated with it?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, expressions, phrase-requests

I would, quite simply, like to know what the word is for something that could happen in any place; similar to the word "timeless", though that refers to something that could happen during any time. I would really appreciate help finding an appropriate word!

An example sentence would be an answer to "Where is it set?": "It is [word] so it could be applied to any place." I understand that I could just use the secondary explanation but wish to look for a specific word.

Comment: If you meant *everywhere* (as opposed to *anywhere*), you could use *ubiquitous*.

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where the word/phrase would be used? *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't timeless mean more not _affected_ by time? As in the relevance, beauty, or some other trait doesn't change with the passage of time?

Comment: And to coin a compound, *location-agnostic* (or *setting-agnostic*).

Comment: I have added an example. I hope it's specific enough to understand. Also, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: How about **"universal"**?

Comment: I agree with @NexTerren 's  feeling about your possible misconstruing of “timeless.”  If by “timeless” you mean “not/non-time-specific” then its place/location parallel could be “not/non-location-specific” or to limit the scope a bit of Max's  great “universal,” maybe “[spatially] **global**.”

Comment: "Global" or "universal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parallel construction **placeless** is a perfectly respectable word:

> 1. lacking a fixed location
> 2. indistinguishable from other such places in appearance or character
>      -http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/placeless

Answer (score 2):

"Universal" means all over the world as well as common in many eras. For instance, it is a universal experience to hear hungry babies crying.

Answer (score 1):

I think that *ubiquitous* captures both meanings , timeless and placeless.

> **ubiquitous** - existing or being everywhere, especially at the same time; omnipresent:

-http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ubiquitous